# Why using `std::reverse_iterator` doesn't invoke UB?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I was working with [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) today and was thinking about how it works with values created by calling `begin` on a container. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), if I have `reverse_iterator r` constructed from `iterator i`, the following has to hold `&*r == &*(i-1)`.

However, this would mean that if I write this

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto iter = std::make_reverse_iterator(begin(vec));
```

iter now points to piece of memory that is placed before `begin(vec)`, which is out of bounds. By strict interpretation of C++ standard, this invokes UB.

*(There is specific provision for pointer/iterator to element 1-past-the-end of the array, but as far as I know, none for pointer/iterator to element 1-ahead-of-the-start of an array.)*

So, am I reading the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) wrong, or is there a specific provision in the standard for this case, or is it that when using `reverse_iterator`, the whole array is taken as reversed and as such, pointer to ahead of the array is actually pointer past the end?

Comment: `the following has to hold &*r == &*(i-1)` ... except for `r == rend()`, which is not dereferenceable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik As far as I know, just creating a pointer that is out of bounds is UB.

Comment: In what sense is an iterator - an instance of some class and not a pointer - is "out of bounds"? `r.base() == vec.begin()`. `*r` does indeed exhibit undefined behavior, by way of attempting to compute `vec.begin() - 1`.

Comment: Everything is fine. Just don't *dereference* `iter`.

Comment: @KerrekSB So the offset is actually applied only when dereferencing the iterator?

Comment: @Xarn "iter now points to piece of memory that is [...] out of bounds. By strict interpretation of C++ standard, this invokes UB." How can you define `int* p = nullptr` then ? p points to an invalid piece of memory, but you can still use p : e.g. `p == nullptr` (and it doesn't invoke undefined behavior).

Comment: @Xarn: Yes, correct.

Comment: @Nelxiost: Because the language standard forbids you from pointing to arbitrary bits of memory, but explicitly allows `nullptr`.

Comment: @Nelxiost `nullptr` and one-past-end of an array pointers are both specifically allowed in the standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, I didn't expect `reverse_iterator` to keep the overhead, so I thought there might be some other trickery at work.

Comment: @Xarn: How else did you think it could work? Did you note the `base()` member function?

Comment: @KerrekSB `return pointer+1;`? Optimize for the common case (dereferencing the iterator) at the cost of uncommon case (`base()` call), except that is against the language's rules, which led to this question. Anyway, the question got answered satisfactorily and I think that if we want to continue this discussion, we should go to chat to stop cluttering the comments.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth May I know in which part of the standard this is specified ? I know that accessing the value of an uninitialized pointer is not reliable, but, to me, accessing the value of a pointer to an invalid address is still reliable. @Xarn Okay, I failed on that one ; I would rather have written `int *p; int *q = p;` and then some access to q (no dereferencing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are reading it wrong.

There is no need for reverse-iterators to store pointers pointing before the start of an element.

To illustrate, take an array of 2 elements:

```
int a[2];
```

These are the forward-iterators:

```
a+0 a+1 a+2 // The last one is not dereferenceable
```

The reverse-iterators would be represented with these exact same values, in reverse order:

```
a+2 a+1 a+0 // The last one cannot be dereferenced
```

So, while dereferencing a normal iterator is really straightforward, a reverse-iterator-dereference is slightly more complicated: `pointer[-1]` (That's for random-access iterators, the others are worse: `It copy = pointer; --copy; return *copy;`).

Be aware that using forward-iterators is far more common than reverse-iterators, thus the former are more likely to have optimized code for them than the latter. Generic code which does not hit that corner is about as likely to run better with either type though, due to all the transformations a decent optimizing compiler does.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this also implies there will be a performance hit compared to forward iterators, which will be unmeasurable in many cases but which might be significant in tight, optimized loops.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Unlikely, I think. At least I expect that to be folded with other constants for any half-way decent compiler, resulting in about the same amount of extra-additions/subtractions as for forward-iterators.

Comment: Depends. If you try to (say) call `std::copy` it can be quite noticeable if the library doesn't have pre-optimized implementations for reverse iterators, since then you'll be competing with heavily-optimized code for the forward case.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, that feels like comparing apples and oranges, hand-optimized code vs generic code. Still, you might just have something there, it can happen. Adding a sentence.

Comment: Yeah, from the implementation side it's apples and oranges. But as far as the user can see, it's the same behavior, just an unexplained performance hit. (+1) Also note that it can't be implemented as `pointer[-1]` unless it's random-access, so in reality it'd be `It copy = pointer; --copy; return *copy;`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::make_reverse_iterator(begin(vec))` is not dereferenceable, in the same way that `end(vec)` is not dereferenceable. It doesn't "point" to any valid object, and that's OK.

Comment: @Deduplicator How does what represent which pointers? I'm not sure I understand the question. A reverse iterator would store a regular iterator, accessible via its `base()` method.

Comment: Maybe add that to your answer? Imho, the OP wanted to know that.